postgres upgrade and migration with no downtime
I am looking forward to upgrade azure Postgres flexible from version 12 to 16. I can do it with downtime using pgdump but I want to do it in a way that there is no downtime.
Postgres sql is in azure cloud, I tried to use azure DMS but that does not support to migrate from Postgres flexible server to another Postgres flexible server
because we have huge difference in version that is why I dont want to directly upgrade from 12 - 16, rather want to create a new DB with version 16 and then migrate data to this and have cdc enable.
please suggest any best approach I can take to do this upgrade or anything I need to be mindful of .

I think logical replication is the best method to have near zero downtime migration between different versions.

This is a limitation of the in-place major version upgrade process for PostgreSQL flexible server that this process serves downtime but relatively shorter as detailed in the Microsoft Azure documentation.



This limitation is indeed significant for enterprise applications that demand high availability and scalability.
Currently, PostgreSQL flexible server does not include any built-in mechanism for near-zero downtime major version upgrades. Agreed with @goodfella, it does allow users to set up their solution using logical replication, as described in Azure’s document.

Logical replication is a method of replicating data objects and their changes, based upon their replication identity (usually a primary key). We use the term logical in contrast to physical replication, which uses exact block addresses and byte-by-byte replication

This logical replication approach can significantly minimize downtime, aligning with the near-zero downtime which is your goal.
looking at the importance of this feature, I encourage you to raise a feature request in the Azure Feedback Forum.

thanks,
so is there any specific tutorial or documentation that can help me to set this up, what I understand here is that it is complex and not sure how well it will go when we have 20-30 DB up for upgrade

the documentation i have mentioned in answer have detailed steps to enable and use of logical replication.
